# Creating a new django project using code from a previous project

Tags: python, django, windows, virtualenv, secret-key

I am trying to create a duplicate of an original django project, but with a different secret key, database, etc. Currently, I am just copying and pasting the original project, and then deleting the manage.py file in the new file. After that, I start a new project in the file. Then, I copy the settings as well as the urls from the original project into the new project. Since I want to keep all of my pip installments, I am not going to create a new virtual env, but just copy and paste the original one from the old project(hence creating a new env with the pip installments). I am not sure if this method is okay when creating a new version of the original project. My project seems to work fine after duplicating it, but I am a little worried that there might be a security issue when deploying it, or some part of the new project may not work properly. I hope you guys could tell me if this method is okay, and if there are any better methods. Since I am a beginner, if possible, I would like to stick to this method  if it is okay, instead of writing a bunch of code to duplicate my original project. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to copy a Django project. However, there's no need to mess with `manage.py`. What you should be editing is `settings.py`. Here, you'll change your database access parameters, secret key, and all the other settings. Personally, I go a step further and set these from a `.env` file. Then the only thing I need to worry about when duplicating a project is the `.env` file.

I would not recommend copying virtual environments, that's asking for headaches. Instead, use a `requirements.txt` file. This is a simple text file with a list of libraries to be installed. You can create one by simply doing

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

in your current project. Check this one into your source control – and spin up the new environment in the new project with

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Always remember to keep api keys, passwords, and other secrets out of source control.